# Can I tell Java to use a class other than Object as default base class?

Tags: java, javac

Assume I find something lacking in the default base class Object, and write a class of my own to use instead.

```
class MyObject extends Object
{
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to tell the Java compiler to use my new class as base class instead of the Object class?

Thus avoiding

```
class MyClass extends MyObject
```

and just go

```
class MyClass
```

and have it implicitly extend MyObject using, say a command line parameter to the compile

```
javac MyClass --defaultBase=MyObject
```

That would mean that all Jars and pre-compiled Class-files would use Object, but anything I compile myself would use my own class, except of course, my new base class. (I wouldn't want a circular dependency, would I.)

Comment: there is a way: `class Foo extends MyObject` ... ;-)

Comment: So now you have me curious about the why!

Comment: Ah, you come from a monkey-patching background, right? In fact, you can do it by going to extreme lengths and creating your own boot ClassLoader that re-compiles all class files on the fly - but I do think that you're thinking *agaings* Java's grain. *Why* would you need this ability?

Comment: It's the sort of thing that every Java developer thought about once or twice but you learn quite quickly that it's an idea born out of an incomplete understanding of Java. There is absolutely no rational reason to use a different default base class, it only looks that way sometimes because you got something wrong in your design.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `Object` class within many limitations, but that not really a good idea.  The best solution is to create your own class you want other classes to extend.

If you want to extend Object, the best option is to create a Utility method which takes an Object as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to tell the Java compiler to use my new class as base class instead of the Object class?

No. You can't.

The Java Language Specification ([JLS 4.3.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2)) states that the `java.lang.Object` class is a superclass of all other classes.  If a compiler didn't implement that, it wouldn't be a compliant Java compiler.  At any rate, I know of no Java compiler ("compliant" or not) that does allow you to do this.

@Peter Lawrey mentions that it is possible to change the `Object` class.  This is true ... if you know what you are doing.  But there are dependencies on internal details of the `Object` class hard-wired into other class ... and the native code implementation of the JVM.  If you change some things (for example, adding instance fields or changing method signatures) you are liable to break the JVM, tools in the Java tool-chain, and/or 3rd-party libraries and tools (like your favourite IDE!).  The breakage is liable to be castrophic, and difficult to diagnose.

On top of that, if your change doesn't break Java, you are still stuck with the problem that a *real* JVM won't run your code.  That makes monkeying with Object a viable proposition for "research purposes only" ... at best.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, it is technically possible to override the core classes of the the Java runtime library using the `-Xbootclasspath` VM option(s) (type `java -X` to get the info). However, this is not intended to be done by a usual developer (see other answers to this question).

You can try it yourself by modifying and compiling the source of the `java.lang.Object` to a directory named `core-classes`, for example, and passing the `-Xbootclasspath/p:core-classes` as a JVM argument.